# Keep img ratio on resize - height: 100%;

Tags: jquery, image, responsive-design, scale

I made a template that renders as expected, it comes with different stylesheets to be responsive.

Over 910px, I have a fixed img that takes 100% of the window in height and has a width: auto;. 
On load, the image has always the good proportions, but when I scale down (from the bottom) it distorts itself.

The width stays the same and doesn't scale down.

Is there a way to force the image to keep it's original ratio?

Here's the template : http://bettercheckthekids.com/pirlo/index.html

Comment: try removing `width:auto;`.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** You can try:

```
 img {
 width:  image height in pixels here;
 height: auto;
}
```

**Solution 2:**
If image is inside parent div.you can try:

```
<div id="wrap"><img src="test.png" /></div>
```

Given the above markup you then use these rules:

```
#wrap {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
#wrap img {
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi Milind, did you check the template? I don't see how to apply your solutions given how it is configured. Maybe i'm missing something?

Comment: @cfocket: i can not find the image on template that you are talking about. tell me more about it.

Comment: When your window is over 910px, the website should render like on this screenshot (http://bettercheckthekids.com/pirlo/img/pirlo.png). The image i'm talking about is the one of the soccer player on the left.